# Update a Choice Field in Sharepoint Project [In Visual Studio]

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a newbi in Sharepoint.

I have a sharepoint project, I've defined a MultiChoice field named **COUNTRY**:

```
<Field Name="COUNTRY" ID="{1e450db4-11e0-49cf-9801-ef99a241ed3c}" DisplayName="Country" Type="MultiChoice" Required="TRUE" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE" Group="HR Desk">
    <CHOICES>
      <CHOICE>United States</CHOICE>
      <CHOICE>France</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
  </Field>
```

I then added this field to a Content-Type named **CT_Countries**, then I add this content-type to a List named **LST_Countries**.

Everything works fine and some records are created.

Then I need to update this choice list, but it doesn't seems to be working.
This is what I did:

1/ I updated the field (Rename United States to US, add a new choice China).

```
<Field Name="COUNTRY" ID="{1e450db4-11e0-49cf-9801-ef99a241ed3c}" DisplayName="Country" Type="MultiChoice" Required="TRUE" Format="Dropdown" FillInChoice="FALSE" Group="HR Desk">
        <CHOICES>
          <CHOICE>US</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>France</CHOICE>
          <CHOICE>China</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
      </Field>
```

2/ Delete the content type from list definition then re-add it.
3/ Build and Deploy the solution.

In my back office, I also have previous list.
Could you guys please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your list **Schema.xml** you have another instance of your field definition. You need to update it manually.

[schema.xml - location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fnDe.png)

Other option for you is to delete the list definition and create it again. Then re-add the content type and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do 2 things when you have to update a definition list :

- 1) Update your field and the schema.xml of your definition list.
  This change'll apply for the new lists.
- 2) For the lists already created, change the choice manually or write a script powershell.

Overall, SharePoint have some difficulties to push changes to list already created. We often have to do the change manually or by powershell.